# Avoiding two loops using checks in Python takes 3 seconds longer than running two loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

If I am using these two loops O(n+m)
then its taking 3 secs less than when I am avoiding the second loop using checks O(n). Consider 1st loop runs for 65000 iterations and second for 17500.

```
def maximum_scores(r,d, a , b,sum_1, Max, Min, Max_imei , instance):
    maxScore = int(time.time())
    print(maxScore)
    minScore = maxScore - 900
    print(minScore)
    dataFromInternal =d.zrangebyscore(M_key , minScore, maxScore)
    print(len(dataFromInternal))
    for key in dataFromInternal:
        imei=key.replace(" ","").split(":")[1].split("_")[0]
        if imei not in imeis:
            imeis[imei]=[0,0,0]
        zscore=d.zscore(M_key, key)
        if zscore >  imeis[imei][0]:
            imeis[imei][0]=zscore
    for imei in set(list(imeis.keys())):
            data = r.hget(a, imei)
            if data != None:
                data = json.loads(data)
                imeis[imei][2]=data["GPSTimeLong"]
                if imeis[imei][0] != imeis[imei][2]:
                    imeis[imei][1]=abs(imeis[imei][0]-imeis[imei][2])
                    if imeis[imei][1]>Max:
                        Max=imeis[imei][1]
                        Max_imei=imei
                        instance = a
                    if imeis[imei][1]<Min:
                        Min=imeis[imei][1]
                    differences.append(imeis[imei][1])
                    sum_1 = sum_1 + imeis[imei][1]
                else:
                    imeis[imei][1]=0
    print('cumulative',int(time.time()))
    print(len(set(list(imeis.keys()))))
    print(sum_1)
    return ( Min, Max, sum_1, Max_imei , instance)
```

This is the code without second loop but with checks for those imei which are unique (same thing as list(set(imeis.keys())) in second loop line 15)

```
def maximum_scores(r,d, a , b,sum_1, Max, Min, Max_imei , instance):
    maxScore = int(time.time())
    print(maxScore)
    minScore = maxScore - 900
    print(minScore)
    dataFromInternal =d.zrangebyscore(M_key , minScore, maxScore)
    print(len(dataFromInternal))
    for key in dataFromInternal:
        c=0
        f=0
        imei=key.replace(" ","").split(":")[1].split("_")[0]
        if imei not in imeis:
            imeis[imei]=[0,0,0]
            c=1
        zscore=d.zscore(M_key, key)
        if zscore >  imeis[imei][0]:
            imeis[imei][0]=zscore
            f=1
    # for imei in set(list(imeis.keys())):
        if c!=1:
            continue
        data = r.hget(a, imei)
        if data != None:
            data = json.loads(data)
            imeis[imei][2]=data["GPSTimeLong"]
            if f!=1:
                continue
            if imeis[imei][0] != imeis[imei][2]:
                imeis[imei][1]=abs(imeis[imei][0]-imeis[imei][2])
                if imeis[imei][1]>Max:
                    Max=imeis[imei][1]
                    Max_imei=imei
                    instance = a
                if imeis[imei][1]<Min:
                    Min=imeis[imei][1]
                differences.append(imeis[imei][1])
                sum_1 = sum_1 + imeis[imei][1]
            else:
                imeis[imei][1]=0
    print('cumulative',int(time.time()))
    print(len(set(list(imeis.keys()))))
    print(sum_1)
    return ( Min, Max, sum_1, Max_imei , instance)
```

Is 'if' acting as overhead?

Comment: keys are unique, why are you doing `set(list(imeis.keys()))` in the first code?  `imeis.keys()` will already return an iterable with unique keys.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki thanks for your comment but can we please move to to actual question.

Comment: hard to know, since you are using a variable `imeis` that is not declared anywhere and not passed as a parameter. Your code won't even run, which makes both codes take an infinite time to complete.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry for the inconvenience, its actually defined above this function block as global variable as `imieis=dict()`